# Touchable Opacity onPressIn color change

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I have the following code in my RN application.

```
 <TouchableOpacity
   // onPress={onPress}
   onPressIn={this.handlePressIn}
   onPressOut={this.handlePressOut}
   disabled={disabled}
   style={[
     styles.button,
     buttonStyle,
     this.buttonStyles(),
   ]}
   >
     <Text>Hello</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

I want to change the color of TouchableOpacity when it is being pressed. So, in onPressIn, I changed the color to darkRed, but it display a light red or something similar to that. No dark color can be set there. What is the issue here? How can I change the color till I onPressOut? The color should be a dark one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution. Set your activeOpacity={1} in your TouchableOpacity.

```
 <TouchableOpacity
   onPress={onPress}
   activeOpacity={1}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**

I guess I overengineered it a little bit. You can simply use the `activeOpacity={1}` prop.

**Problem:**

The problem is that `TouchableOpacity` already provides feedback by reducing the opacity of the button, allowing the background to be seen through while the user is pressing down. So even if you change the backgroundcolor of the button, you won't notice it. Fortunately, I have a solution for you.

**Solution:**

You can use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` together with an additional View to create your wanted behavior.

**Code:**

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
onPressIn={() => this.setState({pressIn: true })}
onPressOut={() => this.setState({pressIn: false})}
>
<View
// change the color depending on state 
style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.pressIn ? '#4c7d4c': '#98FB98'}} 
>
   <Text> Custom Button </Text>
</View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

**Output:**

[image: demo]

**Working Example:**

https://snack.expo.io/@tim1717/quiet-watermelon